# Recursive assembly Call though no recursion in source code

Tags: assembly, instructions

I have a code fragment from a dump which I want to understand.
What bothers me most, are the (seemingly) recursive calls like

bd604: e8 fc ff ff ff call  bd605  + 0xb5

What do they do? I don't use recursion in the original function.

> Thanks@schnaader
>
> it seems as if the calls make cld and jump to EAX

EDIT: full dmp of my function

```
00bd550 <SendData>:
SendData():
   bd550:   55                      push   %ebp
   bd551:   57                      push   %edi
   bd552:   56                      push   %esi
   bd553:   53                      push   %ebx
   bd554:   83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
   bd557:   8b 35 74 a2 06 00       mov    0x6a274,%esi
   bd55d:   8b 1d ac a2 06 00       mov    0x6a2ac,%ebx
   bd563:   dd 44 24 40             fldl   0x40(%esp,1)
   bd567:   66 c7 44 24 0e 00 00    movw   $0x0,0xe(%esp,1)
   bd56e:   83 eb 18                sub    $0x18,%ebx
   bd571:   85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
   bd573:   dd 5c 24 18             fstpl  0x18(%esp,1)
   bd577:   dd 44 24 48             fldl   0x48(%esp,1)
   bd57b:   dd 5c 24 10             fstpl  0x10(%esp,1)
   bd57f:   0f 85 b2 00 00 00       jne    bd637 <SendData+0xe7>
   bd585:   8b 7c 24 38             mov    0x38(%esp,1),%edi
   bd589:   89 dd                   mov    %ebx,%ebp
   bd58b:   c1 fd 02                sar    $0x2,%ebp
   bd58e:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
   bd590:   0f 8e 99 00 00 00       jle    bd62f <SendData+0xdf>
   bd596:   8d 76 00                lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
   bd599:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,1),%edi
   bd5a0:   0f b7 74 24 0e          movzwl 0xe(%esp,1),%esi
   bd5a5:   39 ef                   cmp    %ebp,%edi
   bd5a7:   89 e8                   mov    %ebp,%eax
   bd5a9:   0f 4e c7                cmovle %edi,%eax
   bd5ac:   dd 44 24 18             fldl   0x18(%esp,1)
   bd5b0:   89 c5                   mov    %eax,%ebp
   bd5b2:   8d 1c ad 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%ebp,4),%ebx
   bd5b9:   29 ef                   sub    %ebp,%edi
   bd5bb:   01 c6                   add    %eax,%esi
   bd5bd:   a1 a8 a2 06 00          mov    0x6a2a8,%eax
   bd5c2:   8d 56 ff                lea    0xffffffff(%esi),%edx
   bd5c5:   dd 58 08                fstpl  0x8(%eax)
   bd5c8:   66 89 50 06             mov    %dx,0x6(%eax)
   bd5cc:   0f b7 54 24 0e          movzwl 0xe(%esp,1),%edx
   bd5d1:   66 89 50 04             mov    %dx,0x4(%eax)
   bd5d5:   8b 54 24 3c             mov    0x3c(%esp,1),%edx
   bd5d9:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
   bd5db:   dd 44 24 10             fldl   0x10(%esp,1)
   bd5df:   dd 58 10                fstpl  0x10(%eax)
   bd5e2:   8b 54 24 34             mov    0x34(%esp,1),%edx
   bd5e6:   0f bf 44 24 0e          movswl 0xe(%esp,1),%eax
   bd5eb:   89 5c 24 08             mov    %ebx,0x8(%esp,1)
   bd5ef:   83 c3 18                add    $0x18,%ebx
   bd5f2:   8d 04 82                lea    (%edx,%eax,4),%eax
   bd5f5:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp,1)
   bd5f9:   a1 a8 a2 06 00          mov    0x6a2a8,%eax
   bd5fe:   83 c0 18                add    $0x18,%eax
   bd601:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp,1)
   bd604:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   bd605 <SendData+0xb5>
   bd609:   a1 a8 a2 06 00          mov    0x6a2a8,%eax
   bd60e:   c7 44 24 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x8(%esp,1)
   bd615:   00
   bd616:   89 5c 24 04             mov    %ebx,0x4(%esp,1)
   bd61a:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp,1)
   bd61d:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   bd61e <SendData+0xce>
   bd622:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
   bd624:   66 89 74 24 0e          mov    %si,0xe(%esp,1)
   bd629:   0f 8f 71 ff ff ff       jg     bd5a0 <SendData+0x50>
   bd62f:   83 c4 20                add    $0x20,%esp
   bd632:   5b                      pop    %ebx
   bd633:   5e                      pop    %esi
   bd634:   5f                      pop    %edi
   bd635:   5d                      pop    %ebp
   bd636:   c3                      ret   
   bd637:   dd 44 24 18             fldl   0x18(%esp,1)
   bd63b:   dd 1c 24                fstpl  (%esp,1)
   bd63e:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   bd63f <SendData+0xef>
   bd643:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
   bd645:   74 e8                   je     bd62f <SendData+0xdf>
   bd647:   e9 39 ff ff ff          jmp    bd585 <SendData+0x35>
   bd64c:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,1),%esi
```

Comment: Why don't you post the original function along with the disassembly of the binary you get from compilation? Currently, it's too little information to make sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably got this dump from disassembling an object file (.o) . As mentioned [here on OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Object_Files) the `e8 fc ff ff ff` sequence corresponds to a function call before the linking phase, before the final address (in the executable) of the function you are calling is known. At this stage the information about this call's destination is stored in the relocation table of the object file, waiting for the linker to put the executable together.

To avoid this issue you should analyse a dump of the final executable, not of one of the object files. Here the linker's job will be done and the CALL operands will correspond to their real destinations.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Use `objdump -R` to resolve relocations while disassembling.

Answer (score 1):

Using [GRDB](http://members.tripod.com/~ladsoft/grdb.htm) (a real mode debugger), this translates to "call -1" so the byte at bd603 will determine which command will be executed. For example, if this byte is FF, the next command will be "jmp ax" which could get recursive.

Anyway, this rather looks like some anti-debugging/self-modifying code than really making sense.